# Position a Quickfix window to the bottom down globally

Tags: vim

I setup my vim with [amix/vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc). The Quickfix window is below NERDTree, as shown below.

[image]

How do I move it to the bottom down? I followed [this thread](https://github.com/devjoe/vim-codequery/issues/17), and added the following codes to `my_configs.vim`，

```sh
augroup DragQuickfixWindowDown
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType qf wincmd J
augroup end
```

However, the Quickfix window is still on the bottom right.

My desired behaviour like this,

- Open Quickfix window automatically after running :make
- The Quickfix window is on the bottom with full width

[image]

My related settings are,

```sh
"a global quickfix window on the bottom down
augroup DragQuickfixWindowDown
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType qf wincmd J
augroup end

" Open Quickfix window automatically after running :make
augroup OpenQuickfixWindowAfterMake
        autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^1]* nested cwindow
        autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    1* nested lwindow
augroup END


"compile and run
" Quick compile and run kinds of files via ,p
nmap <F10> :call <SID>compile_and_run()<CR>

function! s:compile_and_run()
    exec 'w'
    exec 'vertical rightbelow copen 80'
    exec 'wincmd w'
    if &filetype ==# 'c'
        exec 'AsyncRun! gcc % -o %<; time ./%<'
    elseif &filetype ==# 'cpp'
       exec 'AsyncRun! g++ -std=c++11 % -o %<; time ./%<'
    elseif &filetype ==# 'rust'
       exec 'AsyncRun! rustc %; time ./%<'
    elseif &filetype ==# 'java'
       exec 'AsyncRun! javac %; time java %<; rm -f *.class'
    elseif &filetype ==# 'sh'
       exec 'AsyncRun! time bash %'
    elseif &filetype ==# 'python'
       exec 'AsyncRun! time python3 "%"'
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour: use your own config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this command in a file stored in this path `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/qf.vim` :

```
wincmd J " Forces QFW to go to bottom of screen across all windows
```

Reload `vim` and the quickfix window should be at the bottom.